# How can I disable my Lenovo touchpad with i3?

Tags: debian, i3, touchpad, thinkpad, synclient

I would like to disable my touchpad with i3. Previously I was using XFCE and I was using the GUI to do this. How can I do this in i3 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to disable the Touchpad is to add

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

To your i3 configuration file. If you want to know where that file is run `i3-config-wizard`. In addition to outputing where that file, if one doesn't exist, it'll create it you for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use/install xinput.

It will give you a list of input devices, find your touchpad in the list and it's number = NUMOFDEV.

```
xinput set-prop NUMOFDEV "Device Enabled" 0
```

That should disable it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was
`

`xinput list` pick your device via it's id

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

For example my mouse here has an `id` of `12`

Then:

`xinput disable <id>`
So in my case it was:
`xinput disable 12`